# Unit testing main.py

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

Given a simple Flask app in `main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hi():
    return 'hi', 200
```

I want to write a unit test for it, but I'm not sure how to import `main.py` into `test.py`. I get `NameError: name 'app' is not defined` for the code below.

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_hi(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()
        r = self.app.get('/')
        assert b'hi' in r.data
```

Is there a way to write this test while keeping the same directory structure (basically `main.py` and `test.py` in the same directory)?

Answer (score 0):

If both of your files are in the same folder, then your test file just needs to import the app from the `main` module:

```
import unittest
from main import app

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_hi(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()
        r = self.app.get('/')
        assert b'hi' in r.data
```

=>

```
python -m unittest test.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.009s

OK
```